# Getting a specific part of a value out of a dictionary value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, formatting

Here is my dictionary:

```
article_names = {'AppliedEthics': (14, ['Ngaiklin', 'ip:pD950754B.dip.t-dialin.net']),
'Anarchism': (406, ['Bobdobbs1723', 'Brion_VIBBER', 'DanKeshet', 'David_depaoli', 
'Eclecticology', 'Graft', 'Lee_Daniel_Crocker', 'Peter_Winnberg', 'Quercusrobur', 
'The_Cunctator', 'Tzartzam', 'ip:151.140.141.30', 'ip:206.82.16.35', 'ip:216.103.84.145', 
'ip:24.188.31.147']), 'AmericanSamoa': (14, ['Ngaiklin', 'ip:office.bomis.com']), 
'AccessibleComputing': (14, ['Ngaiklin', 'RoseParks'])}
```

As you see it's in the format of article_names[name]:([number of edits], [n users who edited it])

I want to take the second part of the value for each dictionary key (Aka the part in brackets after the number), and turn it into a count of users before depositing them back into a different dictionary. I have been stumped on this for a while now, and I didn't sleep last night so I'm sure it's easy but I'm beat.

Example of what I'm trying to process it into:

---

```
Anarchism                             [15] (number of users who edited the article)
AppliedEthics                         [2]
AmericanSamoa                         [2]
AccessibleComputing                   [2]
```

I have this function that works fine for my other data sets, because they're not dicts and I can't for the life of me convert this thing to something easier to work with... I feel stupid.

```
def formatter(sorted, type, edit_var, ID): #ID is just to identify if it's that god forsaken dict
    count = 0
    print()
    for line in sorted:
        count+=1
    print("Printing the top {} {} in regards to {}:\n ".format(count, type, edit_var))
    print("{:37} {:4}".format(37*"-", 4*"-"))
    for line in sorted:
        print("{:37} {}".format(line[0], line[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with tuple unpacking:

```
for k, (num, users) in article_names.items():
    print k, len(users)
```

`article_names.items()` turns it into a list of tuples:

```
article_names.items()
# [('AppliedEthics', (14, ['Ngaiklin', 'ip:pD950754B.dip.t-dialin.net'])), ('Anarchism', (406, ['Bobdobbs1723', 'Brion_VIBBER', 'DanKeshet', 'David_depaoli', 'Eclecticology', 'Graft', 'Lee_Daniel_Crocker', 'Peter_Winnberg', 'Quercusrobur', 'The_Cunctator', 'Tzartzam', 'ip:151.140.141.30', 'ip:206.82.16.35', 'ip:216.103.84.145', 'ip:24.188.31.147'])), ('AmericanSamoa', (14, ['Ngaiklin', 'ip:office.bomis.com'])), ('AccessibleComputing', (14, ['Ngaiklin', 'RoseParks']))]
```

which means each item will look something like:

```
('AppliedEthics', (14, ['Ngaiklin', 'ip:pD950754B.dip.t-dialin.net']))
```

and `k, (n, users)` parses out those three parts into three variables.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you effectively want to return the length of that `list` of editors. You can do this with a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> edits = {k: [len(edits)] for k, (num, edits) in article_names.items()}
>>> pprint(edits)
{'AccessibleComputing': [2],
 'AmericanSamoa': [2],
 'Anarchism': [15],
 'AppliedEthics': [2]}
```

A nice easy one-liner; and it seems to be the desired output that you specified in your question. This works because each value is a `tuple`, and the `list` of editors is the second item of that `tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

to return the number of editor you need to get the length of the list of editors inside a tuple inside a dictionary and it is done like this example:

I am using the same dict you suggested:

```
mydict = {'AppliedEthics': (14, ['Ngaiklin', 'ip:pD950754B.dip.t-dialin.net']),'Anarchism': (406, ['Bobdobbs1723', 'Brion_VIBBER', 'DanKeshet', 'David_depaoli', 'Eclecticology', 'Graft', 'Lee_Daniel_Crocker', 'Peter_Winnberg', 'Quercusrobur', 'The_Cunctator', 'Tzartzam', 'ip:151.140.141.30', 'ip:206.82.16.35', 'ip:216.103.84.145','ip:24.188.31.147']), 'AmericanSamoa': (14, ['Ngaiklin', 'ip:office.bomis.com']),'AccessibleComputing': (14, ['Ngaiklin', 'RoseParks'])}
for key in mydict:
    print key, [len(mydict[key][1])]
```

you will get as an output:

```
AppliedEthics [2]
Anarchism [15]
AmericanSamoa [2]
AccessibleComputing [2]
```

Comment: With this, I get "length = [(key,len(mydict[key][1])) for key in mydict]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" thrown at me. I'm on python 3.3.3 so I did my best to adjust for that too. I assume somewhere else in my program something is being made an int and it's messing things up?

Comment: I tested my code on python 2.7.2, no idea where does this error come from. here is an online python interpreter: http://repl.it/languages/Python

Comment: I'm required to use 3.3.3 :( I don't doubt that it works! It's similar to the things I've been trying but unfortunately the differences between 2.x and 3.x have been ruining my efforts in this regard

Comment: here is a reference for python 3.3, len(s) check it out: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#len

Comment: I tested it on python 3.3.2 and it works fine just by adding ( ) to the print function. that's as far as i can help :) good luck.

Comment: It turns out I had code that resulted in the dict being formatted partially BEFORE it got to the format function because when I print it at the beginning of it it looks like:
    article_names: {'AccessibleComputing': 2, 'AppliedEthics': 2, 'Anarchism': 15, 'AmericanSamoa': 2}

still, trying to print("{:31} {}".format(key, mydict[key][1])) still raises a "typeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" :(

Comment: Update: I figured it out thanks to you :) Thank you! I had some weird redundant code that was messing things up

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the result in a list of tuples:

```
[(i,len(d[i][1])) for i in d]
```

and in a dictionary:

```
{i:len(d[i][1]) for i in d}
```